# Is HTTPS terminated at the load balancer or global accelerator in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, load-balancing, anycast

If you connect the [AWS Global Accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/features/) to an Application Load Balancer, and then the Load Balancer to an Instance, where in the chain is the HTTPS request terminated and replaced with a plain HTTP request? Do I need certificates at the Global Accelerator Level *and* the Load Balancer (because HTTPS is only terminated at the Load Balancer), or is HTTPS terminated at the AWS Global Accelerator?

Comment: Global Accelerator is a network layer service. You'd perform TLS termination on either the ALB/ELB or on the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the TCP connection is terminated at the AWS edge by AWS Global Accelerator (see [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/achieve-up-to-60-better-performance-for-internet-traffic-with-aws-global-accelerator/)), while the HTTPS connection is terminated on the load balancer in the AWS Region. So you need certificates only at the load balancer level.